# How do I trouble shoot a program which regularlly falls into a not responding state?

Tags: windows-xp, visual-studio, resharper

Lately I've been using Visual Studio 2008 and about once a day, sometimes more it will lock up. What advanced techniques can I use to determine what is causing the problem? I believe that it's one of the plug-ins I'm using *cough*Resharper*cough* but I'd like to be sure. I've been losing work and I'd like to file a bug report somewhere but I'm not seeing anything in any of my event logs which looks suspect to me.

Working on a Windows XP box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling the suspect plug-ins and working without it for a suitable length of time.

This will at least rule out ReSharper if that's not the cause.

You could also try running Process Monitor from SysInternals.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

or, go to [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com) and follow the links through.

Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity

NOTE: Process Monitor and Process Explorer are two DIFFERENT applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) was your best bet, unless there's something specific to Visual Studio plug ins. Since you are a developer, you may get a better answer on stackoverflow.com